# How to convert a Decimal128 value to a number in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am querying data from a MongoDB database ([MongoDB Driver 3.3](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/)). Some values are stored in `Decimal128` format. The problem is that the following object is returned instead of a number:

```
value: Decimal128 {
  _bsontype: 'Decimal128',
  bytes: <Buffer 80 7c 45 c7 c6 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3e 30>
}
```

I have found no function to convert this object into a human readable number (native JavaScript 64-Bit number). Does someone know how to achieve this?

Comment: Is this in Node or in browser?

Comment: @matthew-e-brown it is Node

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes I also have seen this question. The problem is that I am not using mongoose, but the native driver. So the answers doesn't help me

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, no you have read everything correctly :), It was my fault because I was referring to the false object. Can you post it as an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @Simon - :-) Done! I've undeleted the answer I'd posted briefly. Glad that helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've said the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53369688/extract-decimal-from-decimal128-with-mongoose-mongodb) don't apply because you're "not using mongoose, but the native driver." I have to admit I haven't got into Mongoose or MongoDB. I'll take your word for it that that question's answers don't apply here.

But their *concept* does. The [native driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/)'s [`Decimal128`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.4/api/Decimal128.html) also has `toString`, returning the string version of the number *(although the documentation is **not** clear on that)*, which you can convert to number via [any of the usual means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28994839/why-does-string-to-number-comparison-work-in-javascript/28994875#28994875). Obviously that conversion will be lossy (that's unavoidable), but I assume you know that.

So assuming `dec` contains the number:

```
const num = +dec.toString(); // Unavoidably, this is a lossy conversion
```